# Binary Search Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I've written this implementation of a binary search algorithm, and wanted to know if it was efficient and where I can improve.

```
function search(el, list) {
    // list = list || LIST;
    var LIM = Math.ceil(Math.log2(list.length)),
        lb = 0,
        ub = list.length - 1,
        i;
    while (el !== list[i = ~~((lb + ub) / 2)] && el !== list[++i]) {
        if (!--LIM) return ("NOT FOUND");
        if (el > list[i]) lb = i;
        else ub = i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: (I'd like to give an answer, but must put it in a comment due to 'on-hold' status.) Too many calculations! Don't do `log2`or `(lb + ub) / 2`. Instead, just start from `lb=0` and `len=list.length` and while `len>0` iterate testing `list[lb + (h = ~~(len/2))]`, then either shorten the range to the left part: `len = h` or move to the right part: `lb += 1 + h, len -= 1 + h`, depending on less-than or greater-than result.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7113/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-after-a-bug-was-discovered-by-the-answ)

Comment: To all who voted to close, the original posted contained the line `~~(...) + 1` which I edited to `Math.ceil(...)` ; however, they're not 100% equivalent - `Math.ceil(0) = 0` where as `~~(0) + 1 = 1`

Comment: In addition to all the other bugs that have been found, `search(1, [1, 2, 3, 4])` returns not found instead of 0.  The problem is that the upper bound is being set too high due to the `++i`.  The whole `++i` part is not even necessary to begin with if you just set the bounds correctly and detect termination correctly.

Answer (score 4):

**What doesn't work properly**

As pointed by @Roland Illig's answer, your solution produces an error when `list` contains only 1 item and this item doesn't match `el`.

It comes from the fact that:

- for a 1-item list, `LIM` is `0`
- after the `while()` expression didn't find a match, `--LIM` gives `-1`, *which evaluates to `true`*
- so `if (!--LIM)` is false and the loop continues infinitely...

This issue can be solved by merely changing this test to `if (--LIM <= 0)`

**Possible improvements**

As pointed by @Dair, your names are somewhat cryptic.
For the sake of readability you'd better to change:

- `el` to `searchedValue`
- `LIM` to `tries` (also note that using uppercase is supposed to be reserved for constants, while this data is not)
- `lb` to `lowerBound`
- `ub` to `upperBound`

Also, following best practices, I recommend to use block marks for `if()`s.

All that said, here is a suggested improved (and corrected) version:

```
function search(searchedValue, list) {
    var tries = Math.ceil(Math.log2(list.length)),
        lowerBound = 0,
        upperBound = list.length - 1,
        i;
    while (
        searchedValue !== list[i = ~~((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2)]
    &&
        searchedValue !== list[++i]
    ) {
        if (--tries <= 0) {
            return ("NOT FOUND");
        }
        if (searchedValue > list[i]) {
            lowerBound = i;
        } else {
            upperBound = i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Note: Roland Illig points out this algorithm is wrong, so I wrote this answer under the assumption it was correct.)

## Naming

I think I understand what `LIM` is, many people would argue you should probably just write it out as `LIMIT`. However, these 3:

```
    lb = 0,
    ub = list.length - 1,
    i;
```

I have no idea what they mean. I would write out the names.

## `log2`

```
var LIM = Math.ceil(Math.log2(list.length))
```

It appears you are using `LIM` to provide a termination point for your program. You really don't need this for a binary search. It is unnecessarily complicated. I think you should think more about what you should do instead of me just telling you what the alternative is. Get rid of `log2`/`LIM` altogether.

## One-liners

This line:

```
el !== list[i = ~~((lb + ub) / 2)] && el !== list[++i]
```

Is really hard to understand. Unless you have a good reason to write code like this I wouldn't do it. I haven't seen a binary search that has a line this cryptic. There should be a way of breaking this up into multiple lines.

## Debugging

Given you were confused about the output, splitting up into multiple line might be a good thing as it allows you to isolate where the issue is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong.

It produces an out-of-bounds access when you call `search(3, [2])`.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment + vote to close as broken

Comment: @Janos The original author appeared to be unaware that the code was broken, and it wasn't obviously broken enough to be closed as broken code. (As evidence, Dair missed the bug as well, and already wrote an answer.) Since this answer points out an issue with correctness in an unanticipated case, it is a fine answer.